# Stopping the inferior process in GDB WITHOUT a signal?

Tags: gdb, sigint

Is there a way to stop the inferior without using Ctrl+C (or an equivalent signal sent from another process?)  I'm using a windows platform and am managing GDB from another process, so with no notion of signals, it seems that there isn't a good way to break execution of my program when it's free running without any breakpoints.

**EDIT FOR CLARITY:**

There are 2 processes involved here.  There's process A, which is the parent of GDB.  GDB is managing a process, but it's on a remote host, and we'll call that process C.

When I tell GDB to "run" it kicks off process C on the remote host and blocks either until a breakpoint is hit, process C encounters an error or a fatal signal, or GDB itself receives an interrupt signal.  If working interactively, you would simply press CTRL+C at the GDB command console, which GDB interprets as a SIGINT (somehow), triggering GDB to halt process C.  Since I'm actually managing GDB with process A (and not dealing with it interactively at the shell)  I can't very well press Ctrl+C, and since windows has no native notion of "Signals" like you have in UNIX, I can't figure out how to interrupt GDB when it's blocking waiting for process C to interrupt or hit a breakpoint.

Comment: Can you describe this a little better. Are there three processes involved? Who is the parent of who?

Answer (score 2):

Did you try to take a look at the remote control protocols? for instance, [EMACS](http://www.inet.net.nz/~nickrob/) uses [MI](http://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/GDB-MI) to control GDB, you should check how/if they offer such a `ctrl-C` mechanism, and how they implement it.

**EDIT:** it seems to be [`-exec-interrupt`](http://sourceware.org/gdb/onlinedocs/gdb/GDB_002fMI-Program-Execution.html#index-g_t_002dexec_002dinterrupt-2034) which interrupts the execution.